# Areas of Surfaces and solids

Tags: geometry

How can I merge the formula of volume for a sphere and the formula of area of a circle to create a new volume formula of a sphere that does not contain the symbol pi? It's not possible right ?

(Sorry if the title throws you off were learning about surfaces and solids)

Comment: Hmm. What do you mean by merging the two formulas?

Comment: Well create a new formula for the sphere that doesn't have the symbol pi in it

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's possible. You could do:
$$
\text{volume of sphere}  = \frac{4}{3} A r,
$$
where $A$ is the area of the cross section of the sphere along its equator, and $r$ is the radius of the sphere.
This would be one way to "merge" the two formulas (since it uses the formula $\pi r^2$ for $A$), and the formula does not have $\pi$ in it.

Here is another one along similar lines:
$$
\text{volume}  = \frac{2}{3} C r^2,
$$
where $C$ is the length of the circumference of the sphere, and $r$ is again its radius.

Comment: Thank but how would the area of the circle plays it's part ?

Comment: @EdithMendoza It plays its part because $A = \pi r^2$. But I don't understand what you mean by "plays its part".

Comment: @EdithMendoza: If by "plays its part" you mean that it becomes obvious how the area of the circle, in conjunction with the rest of the formula, gives rise to the volume of the sphere, I'm afraid that's not possible without calculus, or something essentially equivalent to calculus (such as the method of exhaustion used by Archimedes to derive the volume of the sphere).

Comment: And then in that case, it becomes more convenient to use the circumference of the circle, rather than its area; 6005's second expression comes close to representing this decomposition of the volume.